# Any way to format angle brackets in IDEA coding style?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

Any way to wrap and format angle brackets '<>' like brackets '{}' in IDEA?

```
// Given
export class Demo<A extends string, T extends string, P extends string> {}

// Auto format as
export class DemoForamted<
  A extends string,
  T extends string,
  P extends string
> {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way currently, please vote for [WEB-37872](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37872) to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: Keep watching it.